# SAML in java : timezone converts to UTC from Eastern automatically

Tags: java, jodatime, saml-2.0

I am using opensaml to create a SAML assertion in java application. But the NotBefore and NotOnOrAfter time in `<saml2:Conditions>` always change back to UTC timezone even though I specifically use `DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");` in joda time.

Also I tried again to convert it back to EST but even after this below I still get UTC:`conditions.setNotBefore(conditions.getNotBefore().toDateTime(dtZone));`

Because of this is wierd timezone conflict the SAML expires as a result yielding security error.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The OASIS [SAML 2.0 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) *mandates* the timestamp in the assertion be encoded/normalized to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> **2.5.1 Element <Conditions>**
>
> The  element MAY contain the following elements and
> attributes:
>
> NotBefore [Optional]
>
> Specifies the earliest time instant
> at which the assertion is valid. The time value is encoded in UTC, as
> described in Section 1.3.3.
>
> NotOnOrAfter [Optional]
>
> Specifies the time
> instant at which the assertion has expired. The time value is encoded
> in UTC, as described in Section 1.3.3.

...earlier in the spec:

> **1.3.3 Time Values**
>
> All SAML time values have the type xs:dateTime, which is built in to the W3C XML Schema Datatypes specification
> [Schema2], and MUST be expressed in UTC form, with no time zone
> component. SAML system entities SHOULD NOT rely on time resolution
> finer than milliseconds. Implementations MUST NOT generate time
> instants that specify leap seconds.

I think you will need your assertion creating application to translate the desired `NotBefore` or `NotOnOrAfter` to/from UTC to accommodate. Since you mentioned using jodatime, it would be something along the lines of `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);`  If you want the assertion consumer to consider your assertion invalid on or after two hours from now, you would need to add two hours to current time. You can use [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) "plus...()/minus...()" APIs for that:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime twoHoursLater = now.plusHours(2);
DateTime myAssertionExpiry = twoHoursLater;
//use myAssertionExpiry for SAML NotOnOrAfter
DateTime fiveMinutesAgo = now.minusMinutes(5)
//could use fiveMinutesAgo for SAML NotBefore to allow recipient to have 5 minutes different clock time; use 'now' for NotBefore for more realtime/time-critical assertions
```